# Python grep code much slower than command line's grep

Tags: python, performance, grep

I'm just grepping some Xliff files for the pattern `approved="no"`. I have a Shell script and a Python script, and the difference in performance is huge (for a set of 393 files, and a total of 3,686,329 lines, 0.1s user time for the Shell script, and 6.6s for the Python script).

Shell: `grep 'approved="no"' FILE`
Python:

```
def grep(pattern, file_path):
    ret = False

    with codecs.open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        while 1 and not ret:
            lines = f.readlines(100000)
            if not lines:
                break
            for line in lines:
                if re.search(pattern, line):
                    ret = True
                    break
    return ret
```

Any ideas to improve performance with a multiplatform solution?

### Results

Here are a couple of results after applying some of the proposed solutions.
Tests were run on a RHEL6 Linux machine, with Python 2.6.6.
Working set: 393 Xliff files, 3,686,329 lines in total.
Numbers are user time in seconds.

**grep_1** (io, joining 100,000 file lines): 50s
**grep_3** (mmap): 0.7s
**Shell version** (Linux grep): 0.130s

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Python, being an interpreted language vs. a compiled C version of `grep` will always be slower.

Apart from that your Python implementation is *not* the same as your `grep` example. It is not returning the matching lines, it is merely testing to see if the pattern matches the characters on any one line. A closer comparison would be:

```
grep -q 'approved="no"' FILE
```

which will return as soon as a match is found and not produce any output.

You can substantially speed up your code by writing your `grep()` function more efficiently:

```
def grep_1(pattern, file_path):
    with io.open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        while True:
            lines = f.readlines(100000)
            if not lines:
                return False
            if re.search(pattern, ''.join(lines)):
                return True
```

This uses `io` instead of `codecs` which I found was a little faster. The while loop condition does not need to check `ret` and you can return from the function as soon as the result is known. There's no need to run `re.search()` for each individual ilne - just join the lines and perform a single search.

At the cost of memory usage you could try this:

```
import io

def grep_2(pattern, file_path):
    with io.open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        return re.search(pattern, f.read())
```

If memory is an issue you could `mmap` the file and run the regex search on the `mmap`:

```
import io
import mmap

def grep_3(pattern, file_path):
    with io.open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        return re.search(pattern, mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ))
```

`mmap` will efficiently read the data from the file in pages without consuming a lot of memory. Also, you'll probably find that `mmap` runs faster than the other solutions.

---

Using `timeit` for each of these functions shows that this is the case:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 639 msec per loop       # grep()
10 loops, best of 3: 78.7 msec per loop      # grep_1()
10 loops, best of 3: 19.4 msec per loop      # grep_2()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.32 msec per loop     # grep_3()
```

The file was `/usr/share/dict/words` containing approx 480,000 lines and the search pattern was `zymurgies`, which occurs near the end of the file. For comparison, when pattern is near the start of the file, e.g. `abaciscus`, the times are:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 62.6 msec per loop       # grep()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 msec per loop      # grep_1()
100 loops, best of 3: 14.2 msec per loop      # grep_2()
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.2 usec per loop    # grep_3()
```

which again shows that the `mmap` version is fastest.

---

Now comparing the `grep` command with the Python `mmap` version:

```
$ time grep -q zymurgies /usr/share/dict/words

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.003s

$ time python x.py grep_3    # uses mmap

real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.019s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Which is not too bad considering the advantages that `grep` has.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much for all the details and examples.

Comment: For `re.search(pattern, mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ))` to work on Windows, you have to change it to `re.search(pattern, mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0))` and then, I still get an access denied error. Any idea on how to overcome that?

Comment: `access=ACCESS_READ` is documented as working in both Windows and Unix. Try setting the `length` to the actual size of the file which you can obtain with `size = os.path.getsize(filename)`.

Comment: mhawke Thanks, that worked. I also needed to change my `r'approved="no"'` pattern into `b'approved="no"'` due to a `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object` (with Python 3.5.2)

Comment: This is a great answer. Would love to see how boyer-moore algorithm implemented in python compares to these.

Comment: when I try your grep_3, I only get one match and not multiple matches (for a file that has more than one line with multiple matches within the file). To get all the matches, do I need to do something else?

Comment: Consider two things for grep: `export LC_ALL=C` to disable multi-byte and `--fixed-strings` to disable basic regular expressions. This can boost grep to a different level.

Answer (score 5):

Grep is actually a very clever piece of software, it does not just do a regex search per line. It utilizes the [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) algorithm. See [here](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html) for more information.

See [here](https://github.com/heyhuyen/python-grep) for a python implementation of grep for more pointers.

Answer (score -1):

Another source of slowness here is calling `re.search` inside a loop. This will *recompile* the regex for every single line.

Try instead:

```
pattern = re.compile(pattern)
while True:
    ...
    if pattern.search(line):
    ...
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!

Comment: It's true that calling `re.search()` inside the loop will slow it down, however it is incorrect to say that the pattern will be recompiled on each iteration. In fact, the compiled regex pattern will actually be cached, and will not be recompiled each time. See the note in the documentation for re.compile()`.