# Python mmap object complains of a string pattern on Python 3.5.2 (not in Python 2.6.6)

Tags: python, regex, performance, mmap

I have the following code:

```
def grep(pattern, file_path):
    with io.open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
        mm        = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), file_size, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        return re.search(pattern, mm)
```

With Python 2.6.6, I can use an `r'approved="no"'` pattern.
With Python 3.5.2, I have to use a `b'approved="no"'` pattern. Otherwise, I get a `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

Is there a way to use the raw string pattern with Python 3.5.2? I have code that uses the same raw string patterns that I pass to this function using mmap, so I would like to reuse those patterns.

I have tried reading the mmap object into a string but that considerably slows down the performance on Windows (not so much on Linux)

```
data = str(mm.read(file_size))
return re.search(pattern, data)
```

### Results

Working set: 405 Xliff files, 3,860,117 lines in total.
Time measured with Python `(time.time() - start_time)`
**Reading the mmap object into a string**: 29s
**Using a binary pattern and the mmap object directly in the regex**: 3s

Comment: bytes is an alias for str in python2, in python3 they are two distinct types.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, but that doesn't address my question: is there a way to use the raw string pattern with Python 3.5.2?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using mmap?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, performance. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916645/python-grep-code-much-slower-than-command-lines-grep

Comment: how much faster have you found mmap vs .read?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've edited the question with the performance results. It's about 3s (mmap) vs 29s (read)

Comment: Side-notes: You don't need to explicitly query the file size (Python's `mmap` treats a length of 0 as "map the whole file"), and you can save a little work by `open`ing the file in binary mode (you only use it for the `fileno`, the mode doesn't matter to `mmap`, which is always binary). Opening in text mode just wastes time wrapping in a `TextIOWrapper` that serves no purpose. `open(file_path, 'rb', buffering=0)` will open the raw file with no buffering or decoding wrappers; it's not a huge savings, but it's silly to do more than needed.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would probably be to just encode to utf-8:

```
def grep(pattern, file_path):
    pattern =  pattern.encode("utf-8")
    with io.open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
        mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), file_size, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        return re.search(pattern, mm)
```

It will give you bytes on python3 and as I commented there is no difference between str and bytes using python2.

Comment: Thanks, this works beautifully. Can you explain a little further? I understand now, both for Python 2 and Python 3, both the `pattern` and the `mm` object will be a byte object. And the encoding allows as to convert a raw string to a byte object in Python 3?

Comment: I have tried this solution though with a `pattern = PATTERN_SEP + PATTERN_TEXT_DESCRIPTION` where `PATTERN_SEP = r' \|\| '`and `PATTERN_TEXT_DESCRIPTION = r'TEXT_DESCRIPTION  "((?:[^"]|\\")*)"'` and it didn't work. Does this make sense to you? If the pattern uses regex special characters, a regex search with UTF-8 byte streams may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

`bytes` can be raw literals too. If your pattern is only used with the `mmap` (or other `bytes`-like things), you can just use `br'approved="no"'`, which is supported on 2.6 and later just fine (the `b` is redundant on Py2.x normally, but it means something to the `2to3` converter, and will undo the effect of `from __future__ import unicode_literals` on that specific literal).

Sadly, on Py2.x (and Py3.2 and below), the prefix order matters, `br'approved="no"'` is fine, `rb'approved="no"'` is a syntax error. In Py 3.3 and later, either order is accepted (I prefer the latter myself, since it reads naturally in my head as "raw bytes", vs. the more awkward "bytes raw", but portability takes precedence).

Obviously, if your other uses are for strict text (Py2 `unicode`, Py3 `str`), Padraic's answer of encoding (or storing as `bytes` and decoding in other places) is the only option to avoid storing two copies of each pattern.