# Calculating source frequency in Python

Tags: python, pandas, xcode, file, frequency

I'm new to python; I was looking for calculating the source frequency. I have files(sources are in tokens) and I want to find words that are shown in all sources to calculate. For example, the word 'beautiful' in which sources are shown, the result the word 'beautiful' is in 5 sources. I already have the python code to find one word but I need to find all words from the file, how should I change the code any ideas??

```py
from os import listdir

with open("C:/Users/elle/Desktop/Archivess/test/rez.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in listdir("C:/Users/elle/Desktop/Archivess/test/sources/books/"):
        with open('C:/Users/elle/Desktop/Archivess/test/freqs/books/' + filename) as currentFile:
            text = currentFile.read()

            if ('beautiful' in text):
                f.write('The word excist in the file ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
            else:
                f.write('The word doen't excist in the file' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
```

I will appreciate any help from you, thank you!

Comment: in `f.write('The word doen't excist in the file' + filename[:-4] + '\n')` you need to escape the `'` like `doen\'t` not `don't`

Comment: If you're doing this on a lot of very large files for many words, and if performance becomes an issue, you may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38918877/15013600) for ideas for performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you need to escape the `'` character. The way to escape it is putting `'\'`. Like `doen\'t`

```py
from os import listdir

with open("C:/Users/elle/Desktop/Archivess/test/rez.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in listdir("C:/Users/elle/Desktop/Archivess/test/sources/books/"):
        with open('C:/Users/elle/Desktop/Archivess/test/freqs/books/' + filename) as currentFile:
            text = currentFile.read()
            text = text.strip().lower()
            text = text.replace(".", "").replace(",", "").replace("\"", "").replace("'", "") # replace all .,"'
            words = text.split(" ") # split the text
            unique_words = set(words)
            count_dict = {}
            for each_word in words:
                if(each_word in count_dict):
                    count_dict[each_word] += 1
                else:
                    count_dict[each_word] = 1
            for k in count_dict:
                f.write('The word' + k +'excist in the file ' + filename[:-4] + ' for ' + str(count_dict[k]) + ' number of times' '\n')

#             if ('beautiful' in text):
#                 f.write('The word excist in the file ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
#             else:
#                 f.write('The word doen\'t excist in the file' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
```

Comment: That's just text that will show as a result. What I need is to have a result for all words that how many sources they appear.

Comment: I think you should give it a try by yourself. But I have changed the code to accommodate that.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it works to split the words, but I have already what I need is just to compare to see in which files they are shown. For example, to compare the file that contains all words  with other files

Comment: @elle don't forget to accept the answer. Sounds great :)